# Converting ∃ to ∀ and vice versa

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I'm having some trouble getting my head around the conversion of quantifiers.

For instance, I know that $\forall x  \,F \,\equiv\, \neg\exists x \, \neg F$ and conversely. $\exists x  \,F \,\equiv\, \neg\forall x \, \neg F$

However, what if I have $\neg\forall x\forall y \,F $? What's the logical equivalence for this?

Furthermore, is $\neg\forall x\forall y \,F \equiv \neg\forall x\neg\forall y \,F$, or are they 2 difference things?

If they are difference, then I believe $\neg\forall x\forall y \,F \equiv \exists x\neg\exists y \,\neg F$, but I am not sure about how to generally convert.

Any insight is much appreciated. I've tried googling but most results only come up with the simple case discussed above, that I already know.

Comment: Take $\hat F=\forall y F$ and use the above identities on $\neg \forall x\hat F$.

Comment: Which gives me $\exists x \neg \hat{F} = \exists x \neg \forall y F$. The latter is then equivalent to (using the identities above) $\exists x \exists y \neg F$.

Comment: That makes sense - thanks. Could you give me a more general approach on how to select $\hat(F)$? What if this were a long winded query? My main use for this is in tuple-relational calculus queries which can get nasty at times.

Comment: Well, you could think of it in a recursive fashion: If you have a formula of the form $\forall x\, \forall y\cdots \forall w F$, take $\hat F = \forall y\cdots \forall w F$ and keep repeating this procces (doing the same if you have $\exists$s instead of $\forall$s).

Comment: That's a good way to think about this, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, $\neg\forall x\forall y\, F$ is not the same as $\neg\forall x\neg \forall y\, F$. For example if we take $F$ to mean that $x$ and $y$ are friends, then $\neg\forall x\forall y\, F$ means "it is not the case that everyone is friends with everyone", whereas $\neg \forall x\neg \forall y\, F$ means "there is nobody who does not have any friends", and it should be easy to imagine situations where one of these is true and the other is not.

On the other hand $\neg \forall x\forall y\, F$ is equivalent to $\exists x\exists y \,\neg F$.

It's usually more intuitive to remember these rules in the form
$$ \neg \forall x\, F \equiv \exists x\,\neg F \qquad\qquad
\neg \exists x\, F \equiv \forall x\,\neg F $$
or in words:

> You can move a negation through a quantifier if you flip the quantifier to the other type as you do it.

This way, when you have a whole string of quantifiers with a negation at one end, you can shift the negation to the other when while flipping *each* of the quantifier. So, for example,

$$ \neg \forall x \exists y \exists z \forall w \, F \equiv
\exists x\forall y\forall z\exists w\,\neg F $$

Comment: Excellent, that makes sense. What if I do have $\neg \forall x \neg \forall y F$ and I want to convert that? What would the procedure for that be? Moreover, is $\neg \forall x \neg \forall y \,F \equiv \neg (\forall x \forall y \,F)$? I don't think it is, but I'm not quite sure what it's equal to.

Comment: @user3186023: No, $\neg \forall x \neg \forall y\, F $ is not the same as $\neg(\forall x\forall y\, F)$ -- that's the same thing you were asking to begin with. It looks like you might be confused by the lack of parentheses -- so be sure you're completely clear that that $\neg\forall x\neg \forall y\,F$ is really $\neg(\forall x(\neg(\forall y(F))))$, and $\neg \forall x\forall y\,F$ and $\neg(\forall x\forall y\,F)$ are both just shorteinings of $\neg(\forall x(\forall y(F)))$.

Comment: @user3186023: For $\neg\forall x\neg\forall y\,F$ you can move one of the negations through the $\forall x$ to produce $\neg\neg\exists x\forall y\,F$ -- that is, $\neg(\neg(\exists x(\forall y(F))))$ -- and then since $\neg\neg P\equiv P$ this is the same as just $\exists x\forall y\,F$.

Comment: Not sure why but I'm really failing to parse what you mean by moving one of the negations through the $\forall x$ and consequently don't follow what's going on.

Comment: @user3186023: Then I'm sorely confused what you meant by "that makes sense" in your first comment -- that's what the answer is about! Moving one of the negations is just applying the rule that $\forall x\,\neg P$ is the same as $\neg\exists x\,P$, in this case with $P$ being $\forall y\,F$.

Comment: Ah gotcha! I was assuming we could only move from right to left, but we can also move left to right which is what you did in the latter example.

Comment: Ok reading back at this, I really don't know why I asked "Moreover... " in my first comment when that was my original question. It's 4am and I need sleep. However, one final question, when we have $\neg \forall x \forall y \,F$, is the negation acting on just $\forall x$, or on both quantifiers?

Comment: @user3186023: In $\neg\forall x\forall y\,F$, the negation inverts the truth value of the _entire formula_ $\forall x\forall y\, F$. That's the only thing it _can_ act on. $\forall x$ is _not itself a formula_ and thus cannot be negated. That's why we don't need parentheses here -- both negation and quantifiers always range over a _complete formula_ to the right of them. But perhaps you _should_ think of fully parenthesized formula until this is second nature to you: $\neg\forall x\forall y\,F$ is short for $\neg(\forall x(\forall y(F)))$; that's the only possible parsing of the short formula.

Comment: Okay, thanks alot for the help :)